# SVG rotation issue with JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to use a variable inside the rotation function in JavaScript? The script below does not work (x and y will not assigned).

```
var x = 20;
var y = 20;
object.children[0].setAttribute('transform','rotate(-20, x, y)');
```

Answer (score 0):

As `setAttribute` takes as string you can either use string concatenation or template literals (as shown below).

```
var x = 20;
var y = 20;
object.children[0].setAttribute('transform',`rotate(-20, ${x}, ${y})`);
```

As commented this is ES6 syntax. Below is using string concatenation.

```
var x = 20;
var y = 20;
object.children[0].setAttribute('transform','rotate(-20, ' + x + ', ' + y + ')');
```

Comment: worth mentioning ES6 syntax is not supported on all browsers natively

Answer (score 0):

While building the string in place with literals or concat is fine, if you are planning on doing this more than once, I would suggest creating a string builder function for rotate. For example:

```
function rotateStr(a, x, y) {
  return `rotate(${a}, ${x}, ${y})`
  // return 'rotate(' + x + ',' + y + ',' + z + ')' if you can't use templates
}

var x = 20;
var y = 20;
object.children[0].setAttribute('transform', rotateStr(-20, x, y))
```